# Monotouch - Break on All Errors Equivalent?

Tags: debugging, mono, xamarin.ios

I am debugging an iPad app which background downloads data from a web service. Fully try/catch'ed.

While debugging from Monotouch, after a few minutes the app on the iPad crashes. However Monotouch doesn't catch anything.

In Visual Studio there is a "Break on all Errors" option in the debugger. Is there some feature in Monotouch which would allow me to break at the point of a crash on an iPad device and let me look at variables and stack traces etc?

Monotouch: 3.1.3
MonoDevelop: 2.4 (new beta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a catchpoint on the Exception base class: Run->Exceptions and add System.Exception.